# How to separate a row in a CSV and generate another CSV file from it in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file like

```
AdvertiserName,CampaignName
Wells Fargo,Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro
EMC,Los Angeles CA MetroBoston MA Metro
Apple,Cupertino CA Metro
```

Desired Output in R

```
AdvertiserName,City,State
Wells Fargo,Gary,IN
Wells Fargo,Chicago,IL
EMC,Los Angeles,CA
EMC,Boston,MA
Apple,Cupertino,CA
```

I have done it like

```
record <- read.csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Campaignname.csv",header=TRUE)
ad <- record$AdvertiserName
camp <- record$CampaignName
read.table(text=gsub('Metro', '\n', c), col.names=c('City', 'State'))
```

It throws an error.

How to get the desired result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for example:

```
## read the csv file, you change text here by your fileName
xx <- read.table(text ='AdvertiserName,CampaignName
Wells Fargo,Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro
EMC,Los Angeles CAMetro Boston MA Metro',sep=',',header=TRUE)

##  use regular expression to create city and state variables
##  rows are separated  by ":"
##  columns are separated by a comma ","
res <- 
gsub('(.*) ([A-Z]{2})*Metro (.*) ([A-Z]{2}) .*','\\1,\\2:\\3,\\4',
     xx$CampaignName)
## Use strsrsplit to extract rows and columns
## This is a compacted code !
yy <- 
Map(function(x,y)
         cbind.data.frame(y,do.call(rbind,strsplit(x,','))),
       strsplit(res,':'),xx$AdvertiserName)
## create the final data.frame and set names 
res <- do.call(rbind,yy)
setNames(res, c('AdvertiserName','City','State'))

  AdvertiserName        City State
1    Wells Fargo        Gary    IN
2    Wells Fargo     Chicago    IL
3            EMC Los Angeles    CA
4            EMC      Boston    MA
```

Comment: What about the other two cities?

Comment: @user3188390 I update my answer. It was harder than I thought:)

Comment: @astudy Thanks, From where will I get to know all these things, new to R, Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3188390 there are many resources/tutorials in the net (in SO also). Read the base and try to do solve some simple problems.Exercise is the best method to tackle difficulty.

Comment: If I do have another column other than the Advertisername like Identity, what will change in the code?

Comment: Do you mean you will have something like `Identity,AdvertiserName,CampaignName
 id1     ,Wells Fargo   ,Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro`  as input?

Comment: Yes exactly like that. but also not limited to just 3 columns(Identity,AdvertiserName,CampaignName),there may be more columns, a more generalized answer.

Comment: I am actually on look out for the generalized one.How to do that?And thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48421/discussion-between-agstudy-and-user3188390)

Comment: How to format the regex if the data is of the form "Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro" instead of "Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro"